# How to create a shortcut with monkeyrunner broadcastIntent

Tags: monkeyrunner

How to create a shortcut with monkeyrunner broadcastIntent()?

Can I do this?

```
device.broadcastIntent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT", app_pkg_name)
```

Comment: Have you tried the same intent from somewhere else (i.e. android app) and it works?

Comment: I tried to create an apk to broadcast the intent, it works. but that's a little complicated for it has another intent object in this install_shortcut intent. i don't know if i can create such an intent object with Monkeyrunner.